# ERROR STATUS: URL contains outer http

Tags: url, iis, coldfusion, server

I have a COLDFUSION page which except parameters from url and show them in fields. My url looks like this which is working.

http://www.example.com/test.cfm?activeUrl=www.msn.com&secure=False

But following is not working. I have added http before www in activeUrl value.

http://www.example.com/test.cfm?activeUrl=httpwww.msn.com&secure=False

It is giving me following error. "ERRROR STATUS: URL contains outer http"

Can any one help me to solve this problem?

For me, It seems that something related to iis configuration.

Comment: This must be some server side issue, i have tested and both scenarios are working fine. with n without colon after `http` of query param. Check in you Application.cfc or cfm if there is any clue on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohh, i have not checked the application.cfc ONREQUESTSTART method. it has some condition for query string, which is showing this error. :(

Comment: So it turned out to be a "localized" issue? ie Specific to your application/environment

Answer (score 2):

The string in `httpwww.msn.com` is causing your browser error. It should be `http://www.msn.com`, but should also be URL encoded.